# What does Taylor series have to do with this problem?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Use Taylor series to explain the patterns in the digits in the following expansions:

$\frac{1}{0.98}=1.02040816$

$(\frac{1}{0.99})^{2}=1.020304050607$

I was thinking that geometric series could be used but how would you use a taylor series for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x) = \frac {1}{1-x}$ evaluated at $x = 0.02$

What is the Taylor series?

$f(x) = \sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty x^n$

The Taylor series is a power series.

$f(0.02) = 0.02 + 0.02^2 + 0.02^3 + \cdots = 0.020408+\cdots$

What function might have $(\frac {1}{0.99})^2$ as its output and have a Taylor series that you think you could find?

$f(x) = \frac {d}{dx} \frac {1}{1-x} = \frac {1}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty nx^n\\
f(0.01) = 0.01020304 + \cdots$

Comment: For you first question, don't you mean power series?

Comment: It would be the infinite sum from $n=0$ to infinity of $0.02^n$

Comment: But that's not a taylor series

Comment: @user532874 I have filled in the details